# convert GPS latitude longitude to Cartesian X and Y

Tags: gps, utm, gpsd

I found many algorithms to convert (latitude, longitude) into (X, Y)... however, I cannot verify if the results I'm getting are correct.. I found also this [link](http://home.hiwaay.net/~taylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html) which does the conversion online.. but I couldn't manage to get any algorithm which gives the same results as the one given by the link..

I would be grateful if anyone has encountered the same problem and can help me

Answer (score 1):

#### iOS solution

If you're looking for some ready to go code in Objective-C you can check out [UTM converter](https://github.com/palmerc/GeodeticUTMConverter). It is also available as a CocoaPod.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very nice Wikipedia article on [UTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system).  It's got formulas, background, explanations of the different zones, etc...

Answer (score 0):

[Eric SIBERT](http://eric.sibert.fr) has written a handy coordinates converter. You may use it as a validation tool. If you feel like it, you may even delve into the [source code](http://eric.sibert.fr/IMG/zip/source_convertisseur.zip) for scrutinity.