# How to convert UTM coordinate to cartesian coordinate?

Tags: coordinates

i have to convert an UTM coordinate to cartesian coordinate. how i can do this?

I have to do that to convert an coordiante in specific datum (SAD69) to datum (WGS 84).

thx

Comment: Your first sentence has nothing to do with your second one. Is this another question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try proj4. It can do many conversion.

Comment: Yes, this answers his second sentence. To answer his first sentence, my answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

UTM coordinates are already the best approximation of a cartesian X,Y plane you will achieve. Just directly use the coordinates for your follow up cartesian calculations.
But this is valid only for two coordinates withing the same UTM zone.
Don't do inter zone calculations. (This is the draw back of UTM)

UTM coordinates are in meters.

Comment: This is not quite right. It's not Cartesian, it's a transverse mercator projection. To some approximation you can pretend it's cartesian, but it's really not.

Comment: @BenCrowell The goal of a projection, especially the transverse mercator projection is to project 3D space to 2D. UTM was invented such that the end user simply can calculate using cartesian mathematics. I don't know if you have downvoted, but the question was how to convert UTM to cartesian (most probably to do some follow up mathematic calculations). and the best answer is: You dont need to convert. Or do you suggest a better conversion of UTM to cartesian ??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like theres a similar question here : [convert GPS latitude longitude to Cartesian X and Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342732/convert-gps-latitude-longitude-to-cartesian-x-and-y)

with a link to a wiki page which has all you need to know - probably